# Trying to hide burger menu and have text links instead on large screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make this menu collapse at a break-point or media query. The menu currently just has the option of a collapsed menu. I'm trying to add a non collapsed option so the user can actually see the names of the links at full screen. The menu should only collapse on smaller devices. I tried implementing this functionality using bootstrap but with no luck. Bascically I am trying to simply have text links and then when the size of the screen reduces the navbar collapses and the 'burger menu' appears.

CodePen without broken bootstrap implementation.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPaVdO

HTML

```
<body>

<header id="mast" class="">
  <!-- Logo -->
    <h1 id="logo">
      pic
    </h1>

<!-- Main Nav-->
<a id="toggle" href="#"><div class="menubars"></div></a>
<nav>
        <div class="nav-background">
            <ul>
               <li>
           <a href="">Hello</a>
               </li>
               <li>
               <a href="#">About</a>
               </li>
               <li>
               <a href="#">Bye</a></li>
            </ul>  
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica,arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 45em) {
  body {
    font-size: 120%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 65em) {
  body {
    font-size: 130%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 85em) {
  body {
    font-size: 150%;
  }
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 8;
  height: 3.5em;
}
header h1#logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: .4em 1em 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em 0.5em 0;
  top: 0;
}
header nav p {
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #12384E;
  margin: 0 0 -1em;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}
header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: -5%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(10deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(10deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.36, 0.63);
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.36, 0.63);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.36, 0.63);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.36, 0.63);
}
header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
header nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5em 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: 600;
}
header nav ul li a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
header nav ul li a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
header nav ul li a:hover, header nav ul li a:active {
  color: #0e1718 !important;
}
header .nav-background {
  z-index: 99;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
  display: table;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
  -o-transition: background-color 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
  transition: background-color 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
}
header #toggle {
  height: 3em;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 1.5em 1em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: .5em;
  -webkit-transition: padding-top 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
  transition: padding-top 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.01, 0.3, 1);
}
header #toggle:hover {
  transition: top, 0.5s, ease-in-out;
}
header #toggle:hover .menubars:before {
  top: -9px;
}
header #toggle:hover .menubars:after {
  top: 9px;
}

.menubars {
  width: 24px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menubars:before {
  top: -8px;
}
.menubars:after {
  top: 8px;
}
.menubars:after, .menubars:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #EC008C;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.menubars {
  width: 24px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: .2em 0;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menubars:before {
  top: -8px;
}
.menubars:after {
  top: 8px;
}
.menubars:after, .menubars:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.js-open {
  height: 100%;
}
.js-open header {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background: none;
}
.js-open .menubars {
  background: none !important;
}
.js-open .menubars:after {
  top: 0 !important;
  background: #fff !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.js-open .menubars:before {
  top: 0 !important;
  background: #fff !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.js-open .nav-background {
  background: rgba(27, 128, 167, 0.9) !important;
}
.js-open ul {
  top: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg);
  -moz-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(0deg);
}
```

JS (JQuery)

```
$("a#toggle").on('click', function(e) {
$('body').toggleClass('js-open');
$('nav').toggleClass('js-open');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".nav-background").on('click', function() {
  $('body, nav').removeClass('js-open');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to change the display styles/opacity on your desired breakpoint. For example:

```
@media all and (min-height: 1000px) {
  header nav ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .menubars {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyZPGV